# What style of bench is this?

Tags: woodworking, bench

I saw [this bench](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/494903446533511563/) on Pinterest, I want to research around for plans on how to build it but I'm not sure what style or type of bench it is. Does anyone know?

For convenience, below is the actual image.

[image]

Comment: This would be a better fit in the Woodworking area, rather than Home Improvement.

Comment: I followed the link, but not being a Pinterest subscriber I didn't see anything appropriate. Including the actual image, rather than a link, would be helpful. (I also agree with @keshlam that this would probably best be on Woodworking.)

Answer (score 1):

I googled "3 plank bench" and came up with some images of the same style you have pictured